# How to count the number of elements in an predefined array

Tags: c++, arrays

I want to count the actual number of elements in the array.
but if I use sizeof() statement it gives me the size of array. not the number of elements present.

```
int main()
 {
 int a[10],n;
 a[0]=1;
 a[1]=5;
 a[2]=6;
 n=sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
 cout<<"The size of array " <<n;
 }
```

Here it gives me the n value as 10 not 3. Please suggest me a way to derive the number of elements without affecting the performance.

Comment: Use a `std::vector` instead.

Comment: Or `std::array`...

Comment: Why would it give 3? Array has 10 items. Assigning values to array elements like `a[0]=1;` does not change amount of elements in this array.

Comment: @GPhilo That won't allow to count the occupied elements either.

Comment: Ooooh, number of *occupied* elements! Didn't get that, I thought he wanted the byte size of one element

Comment: @MouliShankar You have to define a sentinel value and count elements until you hit it in a loop. Much the same as with c-style nul terminated strings.

Comment: yeah. but i want 3 as a answer.

Comment: What is your definition of "present"?    In your example, there aren't many things you can do with `a[3]` to `a[9]` since they are uninitialised - even accessing their values gives undefined behaviour.

Comment: @MouliShankar: Your array of ints is uninitialized! This means it can contain any number - not just zeros. If you initialized your array to zeros or a value that is not expected to be seen in your program (ex. -1), then you can loop through your array checking if the value is not zero or not -1 for example. Return that number as the "size" of your array.

Comment: What answer would you expect if you also did `a[6] = 6`? Should it be 4 or 7?

Comment: Predefined arrays simply do not change their size. They are as large as you pre-define them to be. It is up to you to keep track of how many of its elements you are currently using.

Comment: @MouliShankar *yeah. but i want 3 as a answer.* -- Write the code to remember you placed 3 items in the array.  There is no magic property in arrays that knows what action you did on the array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int a[10]; // This would allocate 10 int spaces in the memory;
a[0] = 1;  // You are changing whats inside the first allocated space, but you are not changing the number of items in your C array.
```

**Solution 1 (Easy) :**

```
#include <vector>

vector<int> a;
a.push_back(1);
a.push_back(2);
size_t size = a.size(); // to get the size of your vector. would return 2. size_t is the actual type returned by size() method and is an unsigned int.
```

**Solution 2 (Complicated) :**

You could create an `int` variable that you could call e.g. `numberOfElements` and update it each time you add an element.
This solution is actually used in the implementation of the vector class.

Comment: i disagree and down this solution because he has asked for a basic array[] , not std::vector or std::array

Comment: @SkillerDz I understand he asked for that and this is why I mentioned solution 2, that would be the way to count elements in a C array. Solution 1 would be a suggestion he may or may not know about.

Comment: @SkillerDz There is no way to do what the question asks for without using extra memory (unless you reserve one particular `int` value as sentinel, which you can't just assume). Which is exactly what **Solution 2** explains how to do. And as mentioned, `std::vector` does just that for you.

Comment: `std::vector` does not use an `int` to represent the size.   It uses an unsigned type, named as `std::vector<T>::size_type` which (practically, in most implementations, even though it is not required to be) is `std::size_t`.

Comment: @Peter You are right, I mentioned that in Solution 1 but I stayed vague in Solution 2.

Comment: Thank you Max. Even though its not the perfect solution i asked, you gave me some idea to count. As like @SkillerDz said, this is not array but i learnt a concept of array little bit because of this question. Thank you guys

Answer (score 0):

As it have been already mentioned, you should use std::vector or std:array to achieve this behaviour. Declaring simple array means you allocate enough memory on the heap. There is not a way to determine whether this memory is "occupied" with something valid or not, since there is always something (after allocation there are random values on each index of the array).

Comment: There may always be "something" but, in general, those "something"s can't be examined.   Accessing an uninitialised element of an array gives undefined behaviour.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I wanted to explain why there is not a simple way of determining whether particular part of memory has been assigned a "valid" value.